# Pulling back a list of posts from an array in add_meta_box

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta

So I've got a Custom Post Type (called online-cpt) with an add_meta_box of "_useraccess"

This meta box is currently happily holding comma-separated values entered and updated by the admin e.g. 2,3,14,56,6 etc.

How can I now pull back a loop of all online-cpt posts that have say the value "3" somewhere in the _useraccess metabox?

I believe its something like this, but I just can't get the 'value' meta_query to work. Anyone spot anything wrong with the following?

```
<?php
// The Query
$args = array('post_type' => array('online-cpt'),
          'meta_query' => array(array(
                    'key' => '_useraccess', 'value'=> '3', 'compare' => 'IN')
                            ));

$show_onlinecpt = new WP_Query ($args);

// The Loop
if($show_onlinecpt->have_posts()) :
while ( $show_onlinecpt->have_posts() ) :
    $show_onlinecpt->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
<?php
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Or am I missing something else?

I've already had a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right, I've actually solved it myself by using get_posts instead - it pulls back all of the custom posts and then when it loops the foreach, I just reference the meta value itself.

Not sure why wp_query wouldn't work as above, but kudos to me!